# Temporarily disable Time Machine backups to a specific disk

Tags: macos, command-line, disk-image, time-machine

I have Time Machine configured to back up to a disk image. (Actually I have multiple backup disks configured.)  I want to verify the backups using `tmutil verifychecksums`, and I don't want Time Machine trying to back up to the disk while the verification is running.

I tried mounting the disk image in read-only mode, which prevents Time Machine interference, but causes unwanted error notification popups. Is there a way I can temporarily ask Time Machine to disable backups to a specific disk?

**Edit:** Forgot to mention, I would like to do this non-interactively in a shell script and automatically re-enable the disk when the script finishes.

Answer (score 0):

The command-line way would be to run `tmutil removedestination <identifier>`. However, I'm not sure that TM would be able to `verifychecksums` after running this.

As such, I suggest temporarily adding the disk as an exclusion. With your disk mounted, do the following:

1. Open Time Machine preferences.
2. On the lower-right, press Options.
3. Press the (+) button.
4. Select the root directory of your disk.

When you are done verifying checksums, delete the entry from the exclusion list.

Comment: I edited my question with a detail I forgot to mention -- I'm looking for a way to do this non-interactively through the command line.  So for the second option, instead of using the GUI I would prefer to use `tmutil addexclusion`. However, I think this approach won't work as the backup volume is already excluded from backups.

Comment: I tested the `tmutil removedestination` solution and it works; `tmutil verifychecksums` does not require the path to be a current backup destination.  The only caveats are that when the backup disk is re-added its identifier changes, and unencrypted backup warnings are reset (for some reason Time Machine can't detect that the sparsebundle is encrypted).

Comment: I take it that the issue is resolved @augurar?

Comment: @Yes but I don't want to accept this answer as-is due to the issues mentioned in my previous two comments.

Comment: @augurar I'm not sure I understand the problem. If a disk is excluded from backups, such as with `tmutil addexclusion`, the idea is that it will most definitely *not* be backed up to (which is what you are looking for). Why not programatically run the above command and then `tmutil removeexclusion`?

Comment: That's not correct.  If a disk is excluded from backups, its contents will not be backed up (which is irrelevant to my question).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a way to "disable" a destination in Time Machine. The only solution I could find is to completely remove the volume as a backup destination, then re-add it later.

```
tmutil removedestination <id>
tmutil verifychecksums /Volumes/<volume>/...
tmutil setdestination -a /Volumes/<volume>
```

A few notes/caveats:

- When the backup disk is removed and re-added its Time Machine identifier changes, this means you can't hard-code the destination id.
- Any notifications/warnings pertaining to the destination will be reset.
- The volume must be mounted in read-write mode in order to be re-added.
- The `tmutil removedestination`/`setdestination` commands require root privileges.

Depending on your use case, it may be simpler to disable automatic backups entirely while verifying.

```
tmutil disable
tmutil verifychecksums /Volumes/<volume>/...
tmutil enable
```

The `tmutil enable`/`disable` commands also require root privileges.